# F# Convert to literal runtime-provided type

Tags: f#, type-conversion

Said another way, if I want a fully generic function, how do I ensure compile-/run-time conversion between numeric types.

For example:

```fsharp
let f x = x + 1 // int -> int
```

automatically assumes `int` because of the `1`.

My current hack at it is:

```fsharp
let gettype (x:'T) = typeof<'T>  // 'T -> Type
let one x = Convert.ChangeType (1, (gettype x))  // 'a -> obj
let f x = x + one(x) // obj -> obj
```

But this doesn't work since `+` isn't defined for `obj`s

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a fully generic function that adds one to the argument, I suggest you use [`LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/languageprimitives.genericone%5b%5et%5d-type-function-%5bfsharp%5d):

```
let inline f x = x + LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
```

Note that you also need to inline your function, because otherwise operator `(+)` can't be generic.